# Get <<Object dtype has no native HDF5 equivalent>> when trying to save data

Tags: python

I know this question was already on the OS, but I still haven't found a solution to my problem.
I think the problem is that X has dimension 3.
How can I transmit X to data so that the size is taken into account?
In my sample, I try to save data using h5py.
X has dtype = uint8.

```
file.create_dataset('X', data=np.array(X))
```

In this case the following error appear:

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when your numpy array is a ragged array (second dimension sub-arrays are different sizes). eg;
`ragged_array_X = np.array([[3,3],[1,1,1],[2,0,10,90]])`.
A quick fix will be something like: `file.create_dataset('X', data=np.array(ragged_array_X).to_list())`

If this isn't the case, and you don't have a ragged array, then you can just try casting your numpy array to the uint8 data type explicitly. If this instantiation fails, then some part of your array is a corrupted datatype (maybe nan or some other missing value) and you should fix that first.

`file.create_dataset('X', data=np.array(ragged_array_X, dtype=uint8)`

Seems like these suggestions might not be exactly what you want though, since you said "size is taken into account". It seems like your array is 3 dimensional (not sure if ragged or not).

Assuming the worst case: you *really* want to preserve shape of a ragged but 3-dimensional array. HDF5 has a new feature for this:

from: (see: https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/special.html)

```
dt = h5py.vlen_dtype(np.dtype('int32'))
dset = f.create_dataset('vlen_int', (100,), dtype=dt)
dset[0] = [1,2,3]
dset[1] = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

As it applies your example, the solution is simply:

```
dt = h5py.vlen_dtype(np.dtype('uint8'))
dset = f.create_dataset('X', np.array(X), dtype=dt)
```